# How to find the power absorbed by independent voltage source if there is an independent current source

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I have a circuit as shown in the figure below:

[image]
[image]

[image]

I want to find the power absorbed by the voltage source (which I think should be negative, considering voltage sources deliver power not absorb them). Let's say I do not know what the value of V1 is. I have connected an ammeter in series with the resistor. Let's say it gives the following values:

a. 2A

b. -2A

c. 9A

How would I find the power absorbed?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115623/discussion-on-question-by-talha-israr-how-to-find-the-power-absorbed-by-independ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having measured the current through R1, you now have enough information to use KCL to find the current through R2. And the current through V1 is the same as the current through R2.

Knowing the current through R1 you also have enough information to find the voltage at the unlabeled node connecting R1, I2, and R2, and thus to find out the voltage of R1.

No you just use \$P=IV\$ to find the power absorbed by V1.

> the power absorbed by the voltage source (which I think should be negative, considering voltage sources deliver power not absorb them)

The power absorbed by the voltage source can be either positive or negative.

For example, if you are charging a battery, it will absorb power, not deliver it.

Or, if you model a diode with forward bias as a voltage source, it will always absorb power.

Or if you simply design a random circuit with ideal components where the current happens to flow in to the positive terminal of the voltage source, then it will absorb power.

**Example**

To make it concrete, I'll work an example. But I'll choose a different current at the meter in case the values you gave were the ones assigned to you to work out as homework.

Let's say the meter reads 3 A.

Then we know there must be 2 A flowing left to right through R2 (because of KCL).

And we know the voltage at the top of R1 must be 90 V (because of Ohm's law).

Then the voltage at the top of the voltage source must be

$$V_1 = 90\ {\rm V} - (2\ {\rm A})(10\ {\rm\Omega})= 70\ {\rm V}$$

And the power absorbed by the voltage source is

$$P = (2\ {\rm A})(70\ {\rm V}) = 140\ {\rm W}$$

Notice this is positive, because the current source is producing a higher voltage than the voltage source is, and so it is sending current back toward the voltage source.

Comment: how would i know if my voltage source is being charged or if it is giving out power?

Comment: @TalhaIsrar, if V*I (where I is the voltage flowing in to the '+' terminal) is positive, then the device is absorbing power and if it is negative then it is delivering power. This applies to all circuit branches, not just voltage sources.

Comment: and how would i know the direction of current throught R2 . Lets say in part c -9A flows through R2 in downwards direction so now how would i know whether -14A current flows from right to left in R2 or 14A flows from left to right since i would be using the same sign in my power calculation

Comment: @TalhaIsrar, use KCL

Comment: yes i did. If i consider the example with 2A in R1. If i say x current enters the node from R2 side then by kcl 5+x=2 or x=-3A but if i say x current leaves the node from R2 side 5=2+x or x=3A. Now which of these am i supposed to use?

Comment: @TalhaIsrar, your two solutions are -3 A through R2 from right to left (entering the node) or +3 A through R2 from left to right. These are the same thing.

Comment: yes but how would i know what to use when i am calculating power in voltage source since my sign would be different

Comment: @TalhaIsrar, use the passive current convention. The current of a branch (or two-terminal element) is taken as positive when it flows into the posititve terminal.

Comment: @TalhaIsrar, if you update the schematic in your circuit to show the reference directions for the currents and voltages of the resistors, and to name the nodes, it will be much easier to discuss your circuit.

Comment: I have updated my circuit. Btw thank you for your time...If i use passive sign convention i would be taking even -3A as 3A so wouldnt that effect my power calculation?

Comment: You didn't show a reference direction for R2. You can pick either one you like, but we need to choose one to be able to discuss things simply.

Comment: ok i have done both i didnt know which one is right so

Comment: Don't do both. Pick one. Neither one is right or wrong. It will only change the sign of \$I_2\$ without changing any of the actual behavior of the circuit.

Comment: ok i choose the 2nd picture

Comment: OK, let's use my example with the meter reading 3 A. Now from KCL we find that \$I_2\$ is -2 A. And the voltage across R2 is -20 V (with the positive terminal on the right). That means the voltage of V1 must be 90 - 20 = 70 V.

Comment: Now the current through the voltage source is \$-I_2\$ by the passive current convention. So the power absorbed by the voltage source is (2 A)(70 V) = 140 W. Just like I worked out in my answer, but with a switched sign convention for R2. (After I change a typo in my answer)

Comment: ok and now if we did the same with pic 1 it would have been I2 is 2 A. And voltage across R2 being 20V. And thus V1 being 90-20=70 and then the rest like how we did preeviously?

Comment: Yes, but now to maintain the passive current convention, the current of the voltage source is \$I_2\$ instead of \$-I_2\$.

Comment: thanks alot i think i have got it. I have done with -2A and 9A and am editing my quesiton if you could check it out whether i am going in the right direction or not i would be grateful

Comment: and also one last thing. If like in pic 1 i consider current to be entering into +ve terminal of voltage source i hope it doesnt cause any probelms and make my calculation invalid as i read that current leaves from +ve terminal

Comment: @TalhaIsrar Under passive current convention, P is positive when the device is absorbing power and negative when it is delivering power. That means a voltage source will "normally" have negative power.

Comment: i meant that in the solution i did above it is delivering power yet current is still flowing into +ve terminal of the voltage source so is it possible considering i did solve it right. P.s sorry i may sound abit silly

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115627/discussion-on-answer-by-the-photon-how-to-find-the-power-absorbed-by-independent).

Answer (score 1):

1. (A) If the current through R1 is only 2 amps then 3 amps has to be flowing into the voltage source by virtue of the 5 amp current source.

$$V_{AC} = 30 \text{ Ω} \times 2 \text{ amp}  = 60 \text{ volts}$$

2. (B) If the current in R1 is -2 amps then the voltage source has to have a negative voltage value and it has to be taking a current of 7 amps of into its upper terminal (as shown in the diagram). That's the normal current direction for a reversed voltage source providing power.

$$V_{AC} = 30 \text{ Ω} \times -2 \text{ amp}  = -60 \text{ volts}$$

3. (C) If the current flow is 9 amps then the voltage polarity is not negative (unlike scenario B) and so it is supplying 4 amps hence, net current in R1 adds to the 5 amps to make 9 amps.

$$V_{AC} = 30 \text{ Ω} \times 9 \text{ amp}  = 270 \text{ volts}$$

- In scenario A, power is being absorbed by the voltage source
- In scenario B, power is being supplied by the (reversed) voltage source
- In scenario C, power is being supplied by the voltage source

Given that I've calculated what \$V_{AC}\$ is for the three scenarios, it's a simple matter of using ohm's law (and R2's value) to estimate the battery voltage). From that (and the current flow I've already calculated for each scenario) the power taken in/ delivered from from the battery is volts x amps.

Comment: Yes thank you i think i have got it. If you could check whether i have done right or wrong . I have edited my question

Comment: @TalhaIsrar I've added a few more helpful calculations and tips where to go with my method. I'm not going to check line by line your method because I don't do solutions that use kirchhoffs voltage or current laws as I find the laws to be pointless and tedious and dumb down what is actually plain common sense (yes I know I'm sticking my neck out).

Comment: well im just a starter so i dont know much thats why i guess its so confusing for me but i think i got a clear understanding now. Thank you

Comment: @TalhaIsrar As a quick sanity check I agree with the 310 volts you got for scenario (c). The rest is trivial but looks right.

Comment: well thanks alot im pretty sure the other one also went according to how it should have